# Sequential ID generator python ArcGIS

Tags: python, loops, arcgis, arcpy

Hello stackoverflow community,

I only have 2 months of experience with python but decided to challenge myself with a project for a class and eventually incorporate it to my job.

I work with ArcGIS and I want to create a looping script that updates ID's on the field based on the "System" field. Example: If the system field is 'Chaparral' then I want the ID field to start with the letters 'CH-HY' then set a counter +1 that adds a 1 to the an existing ID already in the field like 'CH-HY0006'. Here is what I have now.

## Populate Hydrant ID field

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("Hydrants.shp", ["FACILITYID", "SYSTEM"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if (row[0] == '<Null>' and row[1] == 'Chaparral'):
            row [0] = 'CH-HY{}'.format(int1) 
        elif (row[0] == '<Null>' and row[1] == 'SunCity'): 
            row [0] = 'SC-HY{}'.format(int2) 
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

This is where I'm stuck. How do I retrieve the ID's that are already in the field and get the highest number so I can add 1 to it. I really want to avoid creating duplicates within the same system at all costs.

Comment: You can have a class with a state of the field to be tracked.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only writing to populate the field, instead of reading and writing - you can create a state variable outside of the loop to keep track of the index.

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("Hydrants.shp", ["FACILITYID", "SYSTEM"]) as cursor:
    chaparral_index = 0
    Suncity_index = 0
    for row in cursor:
        if (row[0] == '<Null>' and row[1] == 'Chaparral'):
            row [0] = 'CH-HY{}'.format(chaparral_index)
            chaparral_index += 1 
        elif (row[0] == '<Null>' and row[1] == 'SunCity'): 
            row [0] = 'SC-HY{}'.format(Suncity_index)
            Suncity_index += 1 
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

If you are planning on reading from a pre-existing data, you might have to bring in regex to parse through the 'FACILITYID' and find the highest index.

Comment: Looked into regex since I haven't learned about that yet. I think re.search('^CH-HY', ' ') would do the trick. I'm not too familiar with it though. Can I do a search straight in the 'FACILITYID' field or do I need to implement the search in a SearchCursor loop?

Comment: yep, you got the idea. to find the last index of where you left off, you need to iterate through the entire database using a SearchCursor. If the number found by the regex is greater than the number you stored as the max number, then replace and so on. The regex string will be something like re.search(r'CH-HY(\d+)',{your string}). check out RegexOne to learn more about regex

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve the last ID that's existing I went with Search.Cursor like this for System of Chaparral:

```
CHvalues = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("Hydrants.shp", "FACILITYID", "SYSTEM = 'Chaparral'")]

CHuniqueValues = max(CHvalues)

CHintLastVal = int(CHuniqueValues[-4:])
```

Here is how I implemented it into the loop:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("Hydrants.shp", ["FACILITYID", "SYSTEM"]) as cursor:
for row in cursor:
    if ((row[0] == None or  row[0] == '<Null>' or row[0] == '') and row[1] == 'Chaparral'):
        CHintLastVal = CHintLastVal + 1
        CHstr099 = str(CHintLastVal)
        print('CH-HY{}'.format(CHstr099))
        row [0] = 'CH-HY{}'.format(CHstr099)
```

I'll have to look into re.search though cause I can see this method causing a problem when the integer gets to 9,999 and the int[-4] need to be changed to [-5] to accommodate for 10,000.

Thanks for the feedback guys!